# Vue3 axios Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

I've been following [this](https://adrien.poupa.fr/creating-a-global-loader-component-in-vue-js/) guide to making a global loader component but there's an issue with setting up the interceptors with the config.

Error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')`

I'm using `vue 3.2.2`, `vuex 4.0.2`, `axios 0.21`, and Laravel 8

The loader component is not working and I suspect it might be due to the config error.

app.js

```
<script>
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createStore  } from 'vuex'
import router from './router';
import App from './components/App';
import { loader } from "./loader";

const store = createStore({
    state() {
    },
    modules: {
        loader,
    }
})

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(router)
app.use(store)
app.mount('#app')
</script>
```

App.vue

```
<script>
import Sidebar from "../components/Sidebar";
import {mapState} from "vuex/dist/vuex.mjs";
import Loader from "./Loader";
import axios from "axios";
axios.defaults.showLoader = true;

export default {
    components: {
        Sidebar,
        Loader
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapState('loader', ['loading'])
    },
    created() {
        axios.interceptors.request.use(
            config => {
                if (config.showLoader) {
                    store.dispatch('loader/pending');
                }
                return config;
            },
            error => {
                if (error.config.showLoader) {
                    store.dispatch('loader/done');
                }
                return Promise.reject(error);
            }
        );
        axios.interceptors.response.use(
            response => {
                if (response.config.showLoader) {
                    store.dispatch('loader/done');
                }

                return response;
            },
            error => {
                let response = error.response;

                if (response.config.showLoader) {
                    store.dispatch('loader/done');
                }

                return Promise.reject(error);
            }
        )
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please post the error message you are getting

Comment: @Jacob the error is stated in the question. That's the single error I see in the console and the page shows no errors except all axios calls stop working.

Comment: The error can be tracked to a specific line but the question doesn't contain it. There are several points of failure. Generally error.response isn't guaranteed to exist, and so would be a mistake to access response.config.

Answer (score 0):

Your interceptor arrow function having issues with `config` param

```
axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  if (config.showLoader) {
    store.dispatch('loader/pending');
  }
  return config;
}, (error) => {
  if (error.config.showLoader) {
    store.dispatch('loader/done');
  }
  return Promise.reject(error);
});

axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
  if (response.config.showLoader) {
    store.dispatch('loader/done');
  }
  return response;
}, (error) => {
  let response = error.response;

  if (response.config.showLoader) {
    store.dispatch('loader/done');
  }
  return Promise.reject(error);
})
```

Comment: The answer doesn't explain what issues exactly.